# Rule for some days

Tags: devexpress, xaf

I have a date field in the table.
Monday and Tuesday I just want to be selected in this area.
I tried typing in the rule definition, but does not work this way.
how can I do it

```
[RuleCriteria("Rule1", DefaultContexts.Save, " GetDayOfWeek (TeslimTarihi)==3 ", "Only Monday, Tuesday are allowed!")]
```

also can i use || in a rule criteria ?
thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use || in criteria:

```
[RuleCriteria("Rule1", DefaultContexts.Save, "Not (GetDayOfWeek(TeslimTarihi) = 1 ||  GetDayOfWeek(TeslimTarihi) = 2)", "Only Monday and Tuesday are allowed!")]
```

Comment: This solved my problem 
[RuleCriteria("Rule1", DefaultContexts.Save, "GetDayOfWeek(TeslimTarihi)==1 or GetDayOfWeek(TeslimTarihi)==2", "Only monday, tuesday are allowed!")]